# How to show loading image on dropdown change event(SelectedIndexChange)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a dropdown and grid on my page.On change of dropdown value the grid gets refreshed.The data which is bind to the grid is fetched from the database.When I change dropdown value I should be able to see a loading image on my screen.After the data is loaded the loading image should disappear.How will I achieve this??
Any suggestion will be helpful..

Below is the code that I have used for submit click .How should I modify it to work on dropdown change event.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {

            setTimeout(function () {

                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }

$('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, show it before making the request, and hide it after it completes:

**Html :**

```
<div id='loading-image'>
  <img src='loadinggraphic.gif'/>
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
$('#loading-image').show();
$.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        $('.info').html(data);
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      }
    });
```

Here, in `data.php` you can put your logic to fetch the data from the `database`.

I usually prefer the more general solution of binding it to the global ajaxStart and ajaxStop events, that way it shows up for all ajax events:

```
$('#loading-image').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: what is data.php ?? A php file. I am writing this code in asp.net.

Comment: No problem. You can use asp.net..its just an example. You can write the data fetching logic from database in asp.net file.

Comment: how should I handle selected Indexchange event??

Comment: @ROY, Execute an event handler on change of the index and then put this code inside that handler.